# Automatically change cvars during warmup round?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am running a 5v5 community competitive server on CS:GO and am trying to have the server automatically change to the following cvars *only during warmup round:*

`mp_buy_anywhere 1
mp_maxmoney 65535
mp_startmoney 65535`

Once warmup round is over I would like it to automatically change the cvars back to:

`mp_buy_anywhere 0
mp_maxmoney 16000
mp_startmoney 800`

I haven't been able to find any other sources trying to do this and I have tried to use the sourcemod plugin ['Execute Configs' by DJ Tsunami](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=590466) but even that plugin doesn't seem to have a valid way to target just warmup rounds. Any advice / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!